# Continuously generate random number in python but stop when it generates a certain number

Tags: python-3.x, random

I want to continuously generate a random number between 1 to 10 but stop if it generates the number 9 or 10.

I'm using this to get the random number

```
import random
for x in range(1):
  random.randint(1,10)
```

However, I don't know how to continue from there besides

```
if range<9 :
    print("Again")
elif:
    for x in range(1):
        random.randint(1,10)
else:
    print("End")
```

Comment: Can you please post more / complete code. I cannot make sense of those if / else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> while True:
...     n = randint(1,10)
...     if n in range(1,9):
...         print(n)
...     else:
...         break
...     
6
1
5
7
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `while` loop. So whilst `True` (i.e. looping forever), first generate a `random` number. Then `print` it whatever it is. Then, if this number (`rand`) is in the `tuple`: `(9, 10`), i.e. it is a `9` or a `10` then `break` (exit) out of the `while` loop.

Here is the code for the steps outlined above:

```
import random
while True:
   rand = random.randint(1, 10)
   print(rand)
   if rand in (9, 10):
       break
```

which, for me, gave the *random* `output` of:

```
2
3
6
7
9
```

*note how it stopped when it reached `9`*

---

The code could actually be written slightly shorter and more efficiently, if we just simply check `if rand > 8` as if it passes this, it must be  `9` or a `10`. This will make the code run faster as at the processor level, this would be quicker to process. However, two things to note are that this wouldn't work if you wanted to stop when you reach other numbers such as say `4` or `8`. Also, at this scale, efficiency isn't really something worth worrying about.

Nevertheless, you could still use the following to achieve the same result:

```
import random
while True:
   rand = random.randint(1, 10)
   print(rand)
   if rand > 8:
       break
```