# How to connect random number generation to an item to print in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, stack

I am using this code below to generate a number between 1 to 10 continuously until it generates either 9 or 10 before it stops

```
import random
while True:
   rand = random.randint(1, 10)
   print(rand)
   if rand > 8:
       break
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477745/9003921

I want to display another item if it generates a number from 1 to 8 for example if it generates the number 3 I want it to print out a name in order from a stack data structure. If it generates the numbers 9 or 10 it would break.

An example of the stack data structure

1. Mary
2. Peter
3. Bob
4. John
5. Kim

The stack code I'm using is

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.container = []  

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.size() == 0   

     def push(self, item):
         self.container.append(item)  

     def peek(self) :
         if self.size()>0 :
             return self.container[-1]
         else :
             return None

     def pop(self):
         return self.container.pop()  

     def size(self):
         return len(self.container)
```

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ***think*** this is what you want. It generates a random number from 1-10 and prints the number. It does this infinitely unless the  number is greater than 8 (9 or 10) - (as in the question). The method `printItem` is called when the number is equal to 3 (this can be changed). This method has one non-self parameter called `run` (can be renamed). This is what changes which name is printed. It prints the names in the order of the stack - last item is printed first - you could always change this if it is not the order that you want. `run` is used as an index for the `Stack`, which one is subtracted from each time the method is called. Here is the code, you can try it out:

```
import random
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []  

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size() == 0   

    def push(self, item):
        self.container.append(item)  

    def peek(self) :
        if self.size()>0 :
            return self.container[-1]
        else :
            return None

    def pop(self):
        return self.container.pop()  

    def size(self):
        return len(self.container)

    def printItem(self, run):
        print(self.container[run]) # Prints last item/name


# The stack is called 'Names'
Names = Stack()
# Adds names to the stack
Names.push('Mary')
Names.push('Peter')
Names.push('Bob')
Names.push('John')
Names.push('Kim')
# sets run to -1 (last (first) item in stack)
run = -1
while True:
    rand = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(rand)
    if rand > 8:
        break
    elif rand == 3:
        # Calls printItem with run as parameter
        Names.printItem(run)
        run-=1 # Subtracts one from run
        # Sets run to -1 again if all names have been printed
        if run<(-1*Names.size()):
            run = -1
```

I hope this helped!
Just FYI, if you wanted `run` to be a variable specific to the object, you would just add it to Stack's `__init__` method.