# How to connect random number generation to item to print in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47478902/9003921

I am using this code to generate a random number. If the number generated is less than 9, I want it to print a name along with it, if the number is 9 or 10, I want the loop to break.

```
import random
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []  

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.size() == 0   

def push(self, item):
    self.container.append(item)  

def peek(self) :
    if self.size()>0 :
        return self.container[-1]
    else :
        return None

def pop(self):
    return self.container.pop()  

def size(self):
    return len(self.container)

def printItem(self, run):
    print(self.container[run]) # Prints last item/name



import random

while True:
    rand = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(rand)
    if rand > 8:
       break




Names = Stack()

Names.push('Mary')
Names.push('Peter')
Names.push('Bob')
Names.push('John')
Names.push('Kim')

run = -1

while True:
    rand = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(rand)
    if rand > 8:
        break
    elif rand:
        # Calls printItem with run as parameter
        Names.printItem(run)
        run-=1 # Subtracts one from run
        # Sets run to -1 again if all names have been printed
        if run<(-1*Names.size()):
            run = -1'
```

When answered in the link above, it still does not print a name with every number less than 9. A sample output it gave was

```
5
8
10
4
Kim
7
John
1
Bob
2
Peter
7
Mary
2
Kim
10
```

and another

```
9
3
Kim
7
John
1
Bob
6
Peter
10
```

did not exit when it was 9 or 10

Comment: You have only 5 entries, why would you expect it to work for values of `run` greater than 4?  Also: `if rand > 8: break; elif rand < 9: ...` is redundant.

Comment: thank you, how do i make the entires loop? i took out < 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code works in the way you wanted. Just, you got confused with the output. Let me explain your second output in your question:

```
9     -> It breaks the first loop
3     -> rand is 3 
Kim   -> It prints 3rd item
7     -> rand is 7
John  -> It prints 7th item
1     -> rand is 1
Bob   -> It prints 1st item
6     -> rand is 6
Peter -> It prints 6th item
10    -> It breaks the second loop
```

If you want to see more clear, I would suggest you 3 things to do:

1. Delete your first `while`loop. It is useless.
2. Change your `printItem` function with:

   ```
   def item_to_str(self, run):
       return str(self.container[run])) # Returns last item/name
   ```
3. Change your second loop with:

   ```
   while True:
       rand = random.randint(1, 10)
       if rand > 8:
           print(rand, "BREAK")
           break
       else: #same with elif rand < 9:
           print(rand, Names.item_to_str(run))
           run-=1 
           if run<(-1*Names.size()):
               run = -1'
   ```

Then, run your code again.

You will see some output like:

```
3 Kim
7 John
1 Bob
6 Peter
10 BREAK
```